# Did Doc Brown warn Marty to never travel to 2020 or what year did he warn about?

Tags: back-to-the-future

The premise of this question is that I remember Doc Brown warning Marty to never travel to a particular year but I do not remember which year it was.

There is [this meme](https://www.instagram.com/p/B_yKQTbAXOG/?igshid=rk11xopn0zl8) (shown below) that makes it look like a warning was given about year 2020. But did Doc warn about some year and if so, what year was that?

[image]

Comment: The meme does not "impl[y] that the warning was about 2020". It uses Doc's expression to point out the fact that the real 2020 has been a crapsack year for a whole lot of people.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

No, there is no such dialog similar to that. The meme is not based on any specific Back to the Future reference outside of the fact that it's a movie about time travel.

Doc does give Marty several warnings (such as not interfering with the past, not divulging too much information about the future, etc); but no specific year is mentioned as a warning ever.

Answer (score 9):

**Yes, but not 2020.**

In [Back To The Future Part 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Back_to_the_Future_Part_II) at the end after lightening struck Doc's DMC and transports him back to 1885, Marty receives a letter from Western Union written by Doc 70 years ago which does have specific instruction from Doc saying,

> Do not, I repeat, do not attempt to come back here to get me. I am perfectly happy living in the fresh air and wide open spaces. I've even met a wonderful woman I'm considering settling down with. . .

It wasn't much of a warning. Doc only insisted Marty not to come back because he was happy.

Comment: This was not a warning about any specific year... it was just a warning to not go rescue him from the past where he was. There was nothing special or bad about 1885; that just happens to be the year where Doc was.

Comment: @Gendolkari: I agree. It wasn't much of warning but only a request in Doc's paranoid tone.